# how to retrieve double array from postgresql database using c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, database, postgresql, npgsql

I am using C# to return double array and write the following code but I got error in `Convert.ToDouble[]`:

```
            string connectionString = "Server=localhost;port=5432;Database=dbtest;User ID=postgres;Password=123";
        NpgsqlConnection dbcon = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
        dbcon.Open();
        NpgsqlCommand dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();

        string sql = "SELECT fcth FROM test01";
        NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(sql, dbcon);

        NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT fcth FROM tbl");
        NpgsqlDataReader dr = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "tbl");
        List<double[]> arr = new List<double[]>();

        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables["tbl"].Rows)
        {
            dr.Read();

            arr.Add(Convert.ToDouble[](row["fcth"].ToString()));  
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < arr.Count; j++)
        {
                try
                {
                    string sql2 = "INSERT INTO tbl2(fh) VALUES ('" + arr[j] + "')";

                    dbcmd.CommandText = sql2;
                    dbcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (NpgsqlException ex)
                {

                    if (ex.Data == null)
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you post error?

Comment: Please read this tutorial no how to read values from DataRow: http://www.dotnetperls.com/datarow Basically what you need to do is to loop over `row.ItemArray` and convert each value to double using `Convert.ToDouble`. You may collect values using `List<double>`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any method like `Convert.ToDouble[]`. Please read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todouble(v=vs.110).aspx.

First, you can convert to `List<>` or `Array` if `row["fcth"]` is array.

At this time, you should to like this:

`Array.ConvertAll(row["fcth"].Split(','), Double.Parse);`

This only example, `rows["fcth"] = "1, 4, 4, 7"` will return array double type.

Second, if you only want to convert string to double.

You can change to:

`arr.Add((Double)row["fcth"]);`

or

`arr.Add(double.TryParse(row["fcth"]);`
 .

Comment: I don't think using `Split(',')` on DataRow is a good idea, because you may access row columns via `ItemArray` property. Beside in my country we use `,` as decimal separator so this would split numbers incorrectly.

Comment: Which reference is used to `Split(',')`?

Comment: Yes, I only example simply if @Sawa want to add a double array to List<>, `rows["fcth"]` should be an array. The `Split(',')` is custom manually, this will change this in his case.

Comment: Yes, I want add double[] to `List<double[]>`, and `row["fcth"]` stored like one-dim array for example `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` saved in one cell. How can I do this?